# Use S3FS Mount As HTTP Server Document Root

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, amazon-s3, s3fs

My proposed setup:

- An EC2 server running Apache or nginx.
- An S3 Bucket in the same region/availability zone mounted with S3FS.
- The Apache or nginx document root set to the S3FS mount.

My question: Is this a tenable and scalable solution for hosting both static AND dynamic content?

Comment: This kind of thing should be fairly quick and easy to set up, alongside a server hosting its content on EBS or EFS. Why don't you just try it? You asked this question a month ago, you could have an answer within about a day if you give it a shot. I'd like to hear how you go. What problem are you trying to solve here? High cost? Have you considered EFS?

Comment: 1 - Because the manner in which I want to test it isn't yet available to me. I'll let you in on my secret idea. If you pay for 5 business level G Suite accounts ( https://gsuite.google.com/pricing.html ) you get unlimited Google Drive storage. It is possible to mount Google Drive with an S3 shim. See where I'm going with that. 2 - I can (And will) wind up testing but I just want to know if anyone has the relevant knowledge to tell me about any 'gotchas' that I might not even notice in testing.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing something like this :

1. ec2 with apache installed on local SSD
2. Dynamic content hosted on Amazon EFS mount
3. Create subdomain for static content and host on S3 with CDN Caching